# Getting Errors parsing FXML file into a javafx program

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

1. Im Getting [These](http://pastebin.com/wnggEY4n) Errors when trying to parse [this](http://pastebin.com/Vsth8PDR) FXML file into my Java Program.The code for when i load in the FXML file and where i get the errors are bellow

   ```
   package mediarealm;

   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.logging.Level;
   import java.util.logging.Logger;
   import javafx.application.Application;
   import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
   import javafx.scene.Parent;
   import javafx.scene.Scene;
   import javafx.stage.Stage;
   import javafx.stage.StageStyle;


   public class MediaRealm extends Application {


        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Parent root = null;
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
         try {
             root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/rsrc /UIManagmentDefaultState.fxml"));
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(MediaRealm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }

       root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #000000;");
       Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 720);
       primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.show();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
   }
   ```

   }
2. It could possibly because of the code Bellow but I don't think it is i'm trying to load in some of the elements from the fxml file into the rest of my code so that i can have full access to said elements with java.

   ```
   package mediarealm;

   import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
   import javafx.fxml.FXML;
   import javafx.scene.control.Button;

     public class Controller
      {
         @FXML private Button ExitButton;
       @FXML private static Button myVideos;

       public static void doshit()
       {
          myVideos.setText("Addison is gay!");
       }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Probably a long shot, but the line

```
< fx:id="myMusic" /Button>
```

is no correct XML, it rather should be

```
</Button>
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't work thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: When I replace the faulty line, the program starts without a problem.

Comment: the `fx:id` must be placed inside `<Button>` and replace the line with </Button> as suggested

Comment: how come i still getting these errors even with the change in that line?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha can't be true, because I pasted the corrected version (1 line changed) into my IDE and successfully started the JavaFX program - so it should give different exceptions.